# Why is this Regex not removing all 3 or more occurrences from a String?

Tags: java, regex

Having a little trouble with this regex.  I'm trying to take an input and remove all 3 or more occurrences of a letter.

## Code

```
String input = "hhheeeelllooo";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(.)\\1{3,}", "$1"));
```

## Actual Output

```
hhhelllooo
```

## Expected Output

```
hheelloo
```

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern doesn't match 3 or more occurrences: it matches 4 or more occurrences - the first occurrence, and the 3 or more following occurences of the same character.

Change the `{3,}` to `{2,}` if you want it to match 3 or more, and change the `$1` to `$1$1` to keep the first two occurrences in the output.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/uKIHtX)

Comment: The $1$1 part - isn't that just the group?  I was reading the docs and it said $0 would be the entire string.  Wondering why / how this works.

Comment: `$1` is the group - the first matched character. If you want it twice, as in the output, double it.

Comment: A little bit of explanation on why the ops regex matches 4 characters, and how it works would make this answer much better

Comment: @Cruncher it matches 1 thing and then the same thing 3 or more times. 1 + 3 or more = 4 or more. I don't know how else to explain it.